# Power 3 fans from 2 AC sources without mixing the sources

Tags: ac, switches, fan

I have 2 IoT enabled sockets with each socket connected to a single load. All of there components are present in a single large enclosure. To combat the heat generated from the loads, I added some fans. I want all the fans to spin if any of the sockets are turned on.
This was my first attempt:
[image: First attempt at adding fan]

Here I used AC fans and directly connected them to the output of my sockets. But, it gave issues because when one socket turned on, it caused both loads to get powered, which is undesirable. A load should only get powered by its corresponding socket.

This was my second attempt:
[image: Second attempt at adding fans]

In this attempt, I switched to DC fans and powered them using SMPSs. I gave the SMPS a common output, but separate inputs. This solved my previous issue where both loads turn on, but my fans were power limited by the SMPS, which cannot be very large due to space constraints. Also, adding 2 SMPSs in parallel feels like a bit of a waste.

Is there any better way of powering the fans? I want to avoid adding another MCU just for fan control, since these are very basic fans with no speed control or feedback.

Comment: Put in a 3rd "IoT enabled socket" and control the fans independently from the load devices.

Comment: These sockets are in the end, MCUs with internet access and a relay. It is completely overkill for the task at hand.

Comment: Sure, I've written firmware for similar products, so I know what's in them. But if an IoT socket is in a similar price range to an appropriately specced relay, then why not choose the easy route?

Comment: Because on adding an MCU, I also need to power it, which necessitates adding an SMPS. It will also need a relay to be able to actually control the AC power. If the MCU is IoT enabled, it will need it's own entry on the server. I will also need a detection circuit to check if any of the AC supplies have turned on. Too much trouble for these basic fans.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. I'm suggesting you add another identical "IoT enabled socket" exactly the same as the 2 you already have, and that you control that socket in the same way in which you already control the other 2. So you just have 3 of them instead of 2 of them, and you turn the 3rd one an and off in the logic of whatever you're using to turn the other 2 on & off.

Comment: Too expensive and consumes too much space. There is a lot more to these IoT enabled sockets that I didn't mention since it is irrelevant to the question. Also, an appropriately specced DPDT relay has only a 10th of the cost, consumes a fifth of the space and is less likely to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4PXrK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A single-component solution using a relay.*

How it works:

- The fans are normally connected to S1 and will be powered when S1 is switched on.
- If S2 turns on, RLY1 will be energised, transfer its relay contacts and the fans will be powered from S2.

You need to specify the relay:

- Coil voltage to suit your AC supply.
- Dual changeover contacts rated for your supply voltage and the maximum current you expect the fans to draw. (Note that the starting current will be much higher than the running current.)